# SQL - Show column names from a sql result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Something similar has been asked before but not answered and it's not 100% the same, what i have is an SQL like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2;
```

I know that I can get the columns of a table using `DESC`, `DESCRIBE` or `SHOW` BUT, that function doesn't allow multiple tables neither SQL queries.

Comment: In what context do you need the columns, i.e. how do you need to use them?

Comment: I'm building a table from php, so i'm getting the colum names and then the rows so i can print the table, that's working great with 1 table because i use "SHOW" but as i said i can't get the column names if i use a query with join (for example), so basically what i need is to get the column NAMES from an SQL QUERY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `mysqli::fetch_assoc()` and `PDOStatement::fetch()` can return a row as an *associative array*, which means that the columns are indexed by column name rather than by number. You can then use the `array_keys()` function to extract a list of the column names, in order, from the row.